# Change default Charset

Tags: phpmyadmin

How do I change the default charset from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I wonder why someone would want to do that ? UTF-8 can display characters of every language, 8859-1 can only display characters of western european languages (and not even a Euro sign).

Answer (score 4):

You need to go to `phpmyadmin > information_schema > schemata >` change your `DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME` with query

Comment: Hi. Not sure where to find that.

Comment: Its on the left side frame you will find it on first bullet and reach to schemata

Comment: That just for signle schema

Comment: Tried this and got the following error: `Access denied for user root@localhost to database information_schema`

Answer (score 1):

Find your config.inc.php and add or edit the line

```
$cfg['DefaultCharset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default charset in your `config.php`
`$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'ISO-8859-1';`

Comment: Hey Stefan. Where do I find that config.php? Im using wordpress.

Comment: Sorry! It's config.inc.php! It's got nothing to do with wordpress. You find it in your phpmyadmin directory.

Comment: Ohhhhhh. Im not hosting my own server. Im with a company so I doubt I have access to that :(

Comment: Well, you could probably upload your own phpmyadmin installation. But if you don't have access to their installation of phpmyadmin on disk, you can't change its config either.