# Em Dash Handling difference between php and rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, unicode

I am migrating an app from php to rails, and am facing some issues in the display of em-dash.
I am displaying a field which according to phpmyadmin and rails console, has the value of "Mon,Tue & Thu: 8 a.m. â€“ 12 a.m." where the â€“ is supposed to be an em-dash (the long dash). Not sure why it is stored this way to begin with..

In php I display with `<td><b>Opening Hours</b><br><?= nl2br($bar['opening_hours']) ?></td>`
and this renders to `Mon,Tue & Thu: 8 a.m. – 12 a.m.`

In rails I display this with `= simple_format(@venue.opening_hours, style: "margin-bottom: 0px;")` in slim. This however just renders to `Mon,Tue & Thu: 8 a.m. â€“ 12 a.m.`

Does anyone have any idea why this happens to begin with and how come php overcomes it? I tried `echo nl2br("Mon,Tue & Thu: 8 a.m. â€“ 12 a.m.");` on http://phpepl.cloudcontrolled.com/ and it just printed it as is..

edit: outputing to `error_log` gets me `Mon,Tue & Thu: 8 a.m. \xe2\x80\x93 12 a.m.`

Comment: getting `â` and the like means you have a charset issue. e.g. iso8859 in one place and utf-8 in the other.  You have to maintain the SAME character set throughout your entire system, or hook the stages together with charset translation logic.

Comment: @MarcB It occurred to me that might be where the problem lies, but I am not sure whr to dig deeper.. do you have any suggestions how to go about fixing this? Is it related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769901/why-is-mysqls-default-collation-latin1-swedish-ci ? Can i fix it with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8 ? How is it that the php code appears to work? My php codebase doesnt at any point seem to specify the encoding of the database itself as far as I can see.

Comment: @MarcB following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773488/change-default-charset I discovered that my db is using `latin1`. Will try to convert this to utf8 on dev and see how that goes.

Comment: my `php.ini` has `;default_charset = "iso-8859-1"`. Could it be that if unspecified, `latin1` is the default, so it works well with the database?

Comment: doesn't matter what PHP's settings are if the db connection and/or db tables are set to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR - The db data encoding was latin1, my rails expected utf-8. Used [this script](https://github.com/nicjansma/mysql-convert-latin1-to-utf8) to convert -> profit!

---

Long version: 
After @MarcBs comment, I took a look at my phpmyadmin, and confirmed that indeed my tables charset is set as `latin1` and collation as `latin1_swedish_ci`. And it also appeared that either php's mysql is detecting it, or that is the default in the plugin.

To verify, I manually set the encoding expected by `php` to `utf-8`, and presto, the display looked exactly as my rails app did. However, oddly, the reverse didnt work. When I set the rails db encoding to `latin1`, the character changed, but not to the right version. Regardless that appeared to be the problem.

To convert the tables and the data to `utf-8`, I first tried the solutions presented at [How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8). They did not work for me. There was no change on the front end.

Finally after lot of troubleshooting and searching, I came across [this script](https://github.com/nicjansma/mysql-convert-latin1-to-utf8/blob/master/mysql-convert-latin1-to-utf8.php) which appeared to do what I needed. I ran it against a copy of the production db, and it worked! It was only after that that I went through it to understand what it was doing.. It basically converts the data to binary, and then back again into the new encoding (`utf-8`) on top of just changing the table configuration.

Through this process, my old data escaped intact, but some of my new data that I had recently imported got ruined, because they were the reverse of my original case. They were imported by a rails script (`utf-8`) into the `latin1` database, which meant it looked fine in rails but messed up in php. But this was a small case, and I just cleared the data and imported it again.