# Japanese character can’t insert from phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, character-encoding

Inserting from MySQL commands prompt is working with Japanese character.

But when I tried from phpmyadmin tool just prompt invalid character.

So I think it is phpmyadmin problem so I try to change phpmyadmin encoding setting but still not working.

Inserted Japanese character data from command prompt is show perfectly in phpmyadmin.

Please advise me

Comment: Show a sql test case including the character? Do other characters fail to insert? What is the phpmyadmin connection character set ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773488/change-default-charset))?

Comment: Do you have `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or `utf8mb4`).  What are the connection parameters?

Comment: If you have a specific symptom, consult https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored